Minecraft on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS crashes at menu after running with Discrete Graphics Card
Title is pretty self explanatory, I am on latest release (at the moment 1.21.3), and it works if I run it without my NVIDIA dedicated GPU (laptop GPU)
